# Count of column within every 30 day range

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So I have a table that looks like this:

```
Person     Product     Date         Quantity
1            A       1/11/2014        1
2            A       1/11/2014        2
1            A       1/20/2014        2
3            A       1/21/2014        1
3            B       1/21/2014        1
1            A       1/25/2014        1
```

I want to find the Count of Quantity where Product is A and Person has a Count > 1 **WITHIN ANY SLIDING 30 DAY RANGE**.  Another key is that once two records meet the criteria, they should not add to the count again.  For example,  Person 1 will have a count of 3 for 1/11 and 1/20, but will not have a count of 3 for 1/20 and 1/25.  Person 2 will have a count of 2.  Person 3 will not show up in the results, because the second product is B.  This query will run within a specific date range also (e.g, 1/1/2014 - 10/27/2014).

My product is written in MySQL and PHP and I would prefer to do this exclusively in MySQL, but this seems more like an OLAP problem.  I greatly appreciate any guidance.

Comment: Can you share what you have tried?

Comment: I'm not even sure where to start to do this exclusively in MySQL.  I could do a nested loop in php for every 30 days within the range and build up a collection.  That's pretty brute though.

Comment: You could always create a stored procedure.

Comment: What is the desired output for date range 1/1/2014 - 10/21/2014? What is the desired output for date range 1/11/2014 - 1/21/2014? I'd like to understand the request better.

Comment: For 1/1 - 10/21, it would return 1:4, 2:2.  For 1/11-1/21 it would return the same, because we're looking at 1/11 + 30 days through 1/21 + 30 days.  The fact that 1/25 isn't in the range of START dates is irrelevant because it falls within the range of d+30.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Another key is that once two records meet the criteria, they should not add to the count again.

This is not relational.  In order for this to be meaningful, we have to define the order in which records are evaluated.  While SQL does have `ORDER BY`, that's for display purposes only.  It does not affect the order in which the query is computed.  The order of evaluation is not meant to matter.

I do not believe this can be expressed as a `SELECT` query at all.  If I am correct, that leaves you with plSQL or a non-SQL language.

If you're willing to drop this requirement (and perhaps implement it in post-processing, see below), this becomes doable.  Start with a view of all the relevant date ranges:

```
CREATE VIEW date_ranges(
    start_date, -- DATE
    end_date -- DATE
) AS
SELECT DISTINCT date, DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL 30 day)
FROM your_table;
```

Now, create a view of relevant counts:

```
CREATE VIEW product_counts(
    person, -- INTEGER REFERENCES your_table(person)
    count, -- INTEGER
    start_date, -- DATE
    end_date -- DATE
) AS
SELECT y.person,
    sum(y.quantity),
    r.start_date,
    r.end_date
FROM date_ranges r
JOIN your_table y
ON y.date BETWEEN r.start_date AND r.end_date
GROUP BY y.person
HAVING sum(y.quantity) > 1;
```

For post-processing, you need to look at each row in the `product_counts` view and look up the purchase orders (rows of `your_table`) which correspond to it.  Check whether you've seen any of those orders before (using a hash set), and if so, exclude them from consideration, reducing the count of the current item and possibly eliminating it entirely.  This is best done in a procedural language other than SQL.

Comment: Agreed.  I was hoping for a relational solution, but I believe you are right.